# fullcalendar background events: background color not shown in Safari / Firefox / IE

Tags: events, colors, background, fullcalendar, scheduler

I use the fullcalendar Scheduler add-on (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/scheduler/)
When I use the code below, this background event is not coloured silver in Safari / Firefox /IE (no color at all...). It shows the silver color perfectly in Chrome.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        start: '2016-04-01 06:00',
        end: '2014-04-01 10:00',
        rendering: 'background',
        color: 'silver',
        resourceId: 1
    }
]
```

});

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *className* attribute of Events

```
events: [
    {
        start: '2016-04-01 06:00',
        end: '2014-04-01 10:00',
        rendering: 'background',
        className: event_silver,
        resourceId: 1
    }
```

and then in css:

```
.event_silver {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

Kind regards, Romain

Comment: Hi Romain, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this also doesn't work for Firefox/IE/Safari. It only shows the background-color in Chrome...

Comment: When you set your resources did you set the eventColor ? example: resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor: 'green' },
    { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', eventColor: 'orange' },
    { id: 'd', title: 'Room D', eventColor: 'red' }
   ],

Comment: Hi Romain, Yes, I have set the eventColor for my resources.

Comment: I'm confused because it works for me with firefox 17. If this (http://fullcalendar.io/playground/jsbin.php?demo=scheduler/) works for you, may be update your fullcalendar & scheduler version

Comment: Hi Romain, that's indeed the version of scheduler I use.
I used two things: background events (= not moveable) to display when employees (=resources) are on holiday) and normal events (= moveable) that can be dragged onto an employee row (=resource row).
The normal ones work perfectly and each employee has it's own color for his/her events. The background events only show up when using Chrome. Not in Firefox/IE/Safari.
They have the properties: start, end, resourceId, rendering, className.