# How to create droppable color in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

Is there any method to make droppable color to your calendar? It's like there's some color prepared and it's up to users to drag and drop to event cell in order to change the color. I was mean cell event color. Can you guys give me a hint where to start? I got stuck.

[edit]
Sorry if i might make you guys confused for my questions. Here i provide one fiddle that looks like what i want. However instead of making it `droppable` event, i want to make it `droppable` color which same like dynamic color concept.
Here is the coding that this person has made for HTML.

This fiddle is not done by me but it gives a good example for my question

http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/15/

Comment: Like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/15/

Comment: This is true for my questions but i want to change the draggable event into draggable or droppable color.

Comment: @AhKing Take a look at the [event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) you have the `color`, `backgroundColor`, `borderColor`, `textColor` that you can style the event with. You also have the same properties. You also have the same for the [Event Source Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) that you can use as a default for all the events in the calendar that doesn't include a spicific style

Comment: Check the change I have made to this jsfiddle on the eventObject properties, it should help you in the right direction. http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/137/

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out :)

Comment: @Ryan89 I have update it a bit. I might say i almost got it. However, i don't want to create new event based on this drag and drop function. I just want to change the color of the existing event. Here is the new updated fiddle .. I almost there..http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/138/

Comment: I update my fiddle so that it can add new event when clicked. Based on the new created event, i want to change the color by drag and drop the color i want from the left panel..Here is the new fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/139/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [className](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115291/fullcalendar-background-events-background-color-not-shown-in-safari-firefox/37116296#37116296) attribute for your events and then define the class in css.

Hope that helps,
Romain